# Is it possible to remove text box from android wear notification page?

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

Is it possible to remove text box from android wear notification page?

I'd like to remove the text box and show only the background for the below page.  The first page notification still has text and a small icon.

Here is a view of the 2nd page I'd like (minus the blank text box).

[image]

I want to do this without having to create a stand-alone app if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setHintShowBackgroundOnly(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html#setHintShowBackgroundOnly(boolean)) method from [WearableExtender](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html) class.

> Set a visual hint that only the background image of this notification
>   should be displayed, and other semantic content should be hidden. This
>   hint is only applicable to sub-pages added using
>   addPage(Notification).

Usage:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder wearableBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    ...
    .extend(new WearableExtender().setHintShowBackgroundOnly(true));
```

Comment: Yup, you are right.  I was applying that to the first page notification.  Instead you need to apply it to the notification that you want to have the text hidden on.  Thanks for your help!